# Deducing that the inverse of a permutation matrix is its transpose

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, solution-verification, permutations, permutation-matrices

I would like to verify that my proof below is sound.

Let $A\in P$ where $P$ is the set of all permutation matrices (only one 1 in each row and column). Also, let $(A)_{ij}$ denote the entry of $A$ in row $i$ and column $j$.

> Proof: $AA^{-1}=I$
>
> So we must have:$$\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n(A)_{ij}(A^{-1})_{ji}=1$$
>
> For this to occur, the instances where $(A)_{ij}=1$ must exactly occur when the instances where $(A^{-1})_{ji}=1$ occur [otherwise our $1$'s would multiply with zero, and the sum would be zero]. This will be in the first row and column, and then the second row and column, etc. $(A)_{ij}=(A^{-1})_{ji}=1$ and we can take the transpose of both sides here and see that: $$(A^T)_{ij}=(A^{-1})_{ij}$$
>
> and hence $A^T = A^{-1}$

Comment: In the sentence immediately after the displayed equation, you seem to presuppose that the entries $(A^{-1})_{ji}$ are 1's and 0's.  That is in fact true (because $A^{-1}$ equals the transpose of $A$) but I don't see that you've justified it at this stage of the proof.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Yes. Indeed, thank you, that's a good point. I have written above it in the semi-final copy: "For the inverse, we note that we have one $1$ in each row and column, and that since we are row equivalent to the identity, some inverse must exist(since we can merely row swap, using another permutation matrix, to the identity) - and also thus, the inverse is also a permutation matrix, e.g. has one 1 in each row and column. "

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess that's fine. It would however have been enough to simply compute $A^TA=I$ explicitly and conclude $A^{-1}=A^T$ from that.

As a sidenote observe that $A^TA=I$ simply states that the colmn vectors of $A$ are pairwise orthogonal and of length $1$.

Comment: I haven't yet studied orthogonal matrices, I will look into them. I thought deducing the result was nicer than simply proving it with the already known result, that's why I proved it in such a way. Thanks!

Comment: Actually I am fairly sure my proof is incorrect, and my double sum, should be a single sum. Rather I want that single sum to be equal to $1$ for all $(AA^{-1})_{ii}$

Comment: It's alright, I patched it up successfully